# R: Gradually put vowels back into a string

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub

I am removing vowels from a string:

```
> gsub("\\B[A,E,I,O,U,a,e,i,o,u]+", "", "string.example")
[1] "strng.exmpl"
```

This reduced string contains 11 characters. Let's say I have space for 12 characters though, so I want the first vowel to be put back in the string:

```
> MyFunction(string="string.example", maxchar=12)
[1] "string.exmpl"
```

Or with maxchar=13 I want the next vowel to be put back in too:

```
> MyFunction(string="string.example", maxchar=13)
[1] "string.exampl"
```

And so on. How can I put back the vowels gradually in regard to how long I want my string to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyFunction <- function(string = 'string.example', maxchar = 12){

  originalLength <- nchar(string)

  while(nchar(string) > maxchar){
    # remove last vowel
    newstring <- gsub("(.*)[A,E,I,O,U,a,e,i,o,u](.*)", "\\1\\2", string)

    # If you run out of vowels to remove, error
    if(nchar(newstring) == nchar(string)) stop('No more vowels to remove but string still longer than maxchar') 

    string <- newstring

    #print(string)
  }

  return(string)
}
```

Not the tidiest but think it does what you want. I added a check that handles the case where the maxchar is shorter than the string without any vowels.